Dijkstra's algorithm where some vertices have only one path
Is there a way to use Dijkstra's algorithm in a graph with some points having only one connection? E.g. subway lines? I tried creating one but it fails if there's more than one line.
I'm trying to figure out how to return the shortest distance + path required (just the path order basically, e.g. 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 3) to travel to all points in the graph shown below, if I already have a matrix with all the distances between points.

As you can see, some points are on the edges of the graph so you need to travel to them, and then travel right back, but the algorithm can't seem to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Dijkstra's has no problems with that case. Your implementation must be wrong. (Although, I don't actually see the issue with the picture. That looks a reasonable shortest path tree for a subway system to me)

Please define what problem you want solved.  "create a Dijkstra's algorithm" is not a clear specification of a problem.  If you want an algorithm, often it is helpful to specify the input, the desired output, and what relationship they must have for a candidate output to be considered correct.

I'm trying to figure out how to use Dijkstra's algorithm to return the shortest distance + path required to travel to all points in the graph shown above, if I already have a matrix with all the distances between points

I don't know what "path required to travel to all points in the graph" means.  Please elaborate on that to define more precisely what that means.  Please [edit] the question rather than leaving information/clarification in the comments.  Please focus now on what the problem to be solved is; let us worry about how to solve it (maybe Dijkstra's algorithm is not the right solution).  Are you asking for an algorithm for the Traveling Salesman Problem?  Looking for a Hamiltonian path?

"path required to travel to all points" basically what I want is the order you have to travel in to reach all points in the graph in the shortest distance possible, ex 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 3

In that case, you are indeed looking for a Hamiltonian path. Dijkstra will give you the shortest distance between any two points, which is not the same thing (a distance is not a path, and a path between two points is not a path containing all points).

oh thanks, i'm an idiot
